# How to capture the Peak Memory and CPU utilization of the process using psutil

Tags: python-3.x, memory-management, subprocess, popen, psutil

**Process P1**:

```
#sub.py
#Find the sum of two numbers

def sum_ab(a,b):
    return a+b

def main():
    print(sum_ab(3,6))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Process P2:**

```
#run.py
#Execute sub.py 10 times
import psutil as ps

cmd = ["python3", "sub.py"]

for i in range(10):
    process = ps.Popen(cmd)
```

The above is the scenario I'm working with. I need to find the CPU and memory utilization of each of the sub process called by the 'run.py' script. Can anyone help me derive the resource information of the RUNNING Processes. How to derive the following in python.

1. What is the CPU utilization by each sub process 'sub.py'
2. What is the memory utilization by each sub process 'sub.py'

Answer (score 2):

With quite a bit of search time and effort, I found that it is possible to get the subprocess resource utilization analysis.

The updated Process P2 is as follows:

```
# run.py
# Execute sub.py 10 times

# Import the required utilities
import psutil as ps
import time
from subprocess import PIPE

# define the command for the subprocess
cmd = ["python3", "sub.py"]

for i in range(10):
    # Create the process
    process = ps.Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE)

    peak_mem = 0
    peak_cpu = 0

    # while the process is running calculate resource utilization.
    while(process.is_running()):
        # set the sleep time to monitor at an interval of every second.
        time.sleep(1)

        # capture the memory and cpu utilization at an instance
        mem = process.memory_info().rss/ (float)(2**30)
        cpu = process.cpu_percent()

        # track the peak utilization of the process
        if mem > peak_mem:
            peak_mem = mem
        if cpu > peak_cpu:
            peak_cpu = cpu
        if mem == 0.0:
            break

    # Print the results to the monitor for each subprocess run.
    print("Peak memory usage for the iteration {} is {} GB".format(i, peak_mem))
    print("Peak CPU utilization for the iteration {} is {} %".format(i, peak_cpu))
```